# count each complete cycle of head rotation

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am working on head pose estimation project where I want to count each complete cycle of head rotation. I was thinking to use if statement but it seems not working.

```
if (((abs(yaw) > -10) and (abs(yaw) < 10)) and ((abs(pitch) > -10) and (abs(pitch) < 10))):
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

Comment: please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre] and [help/on-topic]. SO is not forum to learn programming.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do but the abs(yaw) > -10 statements are superfluous as the absolute value of any number will always be 0 or positive.

Comment: if I understood OP correctly, a sequence of absolute angles, say [180, 90, 0, 270, 180], should result in a total rotation of -360...  or maybe OP doesn't literally mean rotation of the head, but some rolling motion where the "nose vector" describes a cone. that would explain both pitch and yaw involved in OP's attempt...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.